# Create a document index in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to create an index that lists all documents and spreadsheets from a SP site.

I want a user to be able to navigate to the site and then be able to see a list of all documents (i.e. how to's etc) rather than having to sift through the entire site / doing searches to find what they're looking for.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a modern page then insert a highlighted content web part to show all documents in the site collection.

[image]

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Emily - apologies for not getting back to you sooner.  Would that pick up new documents uploaded as well or would this need to be re-run?

Comment: It will pick up new documents uploaded as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at employing this!

Comment: I have had a look at this - it does as you say, thanks.  I don't think it works easily for what I want, I was hoping that I could have a proper index, like A, B, C, etc, and then below A, B,C it would have a list of the sections.  I guess what I am after is a wiki of sorts.  I'm not sure Sharepoint is geared towards that.